# How to validate SAML response and assertion signature using SimpleSAMLphp

Tags: wso2, saml, simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying out the SimpleSAMLphp sample app with WSO2 Identity Server as the Identity Provider. I can successfully login and logout. The SAML assertion and the response is signed.

I want to know how to validate the (response and assertion) signature in the client application using SimpleSAMLphp.

Answer (score 1):

When acting as Service Provider (SP), SimpleSAMLphp will always validate response signature by default, so you don't have to do it yourself. This is mandated by '[saml2int](https://kantarainitiative.github.io/SAMLprofiles/saml2int.html#_response_content_2)', so I guess it conforms to that (in [SAML2Core](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56776/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-07.pdf) it is only recommended).

You can check relevant [SSP code which initiates the check](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/9bc23ba3aedd5742de896e8f0af28a67be9aa1df/modules/saml/src/Controller/ServiceProvider.php#L283) and the
[signature check itself](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/9bc23ba3aedd5742de896e8f0af28a67be9aa1df/modules/saml/src/Message.php#L602).